# Height half fill_parent xml

Tags: android, xml, height, android-linearlayout

How I can do with `LinearLayout` height half `fill_parent` in xml?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">
      <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like do something similar with height.

Comment: instead of fill_parent specify in dp the value required. Like 100dp or anything you want.

Comment: you want your linearLayout to be squared?

Comment: I just want have a half of screen with 1 linearLayout and half screen with other one

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`I just want have a half of screen with 1 linearLayout and half screen with other one`

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#192832"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#193222"></LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Two linear layouts occupying half of the screen each.

Comment: You can also use layout_height="0dp" for fixed height

Comment: Note that `fill_parent` has been depreceated.  Use `match_parent` for API 8 or higher.  ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html))