# How to size 2 dynamic android layouts to fill available space, and each use half if both want more than half?

Tags: android

I'm designing an android app with a layout that has one main vertical `LinearLayout` containing two child `LinearLayout`s, but I'm having difficulty getting the child `LinearLayout`s to size how I need them.  These views each contain multiple other views, including an `ExpandableListView` (i.e. a total of two ELVs, one in each of the two child `LinearLayout`s).  The size of the ELVs are dynamic.  I need the two child `LinearLayout`s to fill the available space if needed, and the second child `LinearLayout` needs to be directly below the first one.  If one of them needs less than half of the space, then the other can grow as much as available space allows (i.e. if one needs 25%, the other can expand up to 75%, and the ELV will scroll if it needs more).  If both needs more than 50%, they each should get half and their ELVs should scroll.  How do I do this?  If views other than `LinearLayout`s are needed (such as `ConstraintLayout` or `CoordinatorLayout`), I am willing to use them.

I have tried using `android:layout_weight`, but these seem to carve out permanent space which creates empty space between the views or unnecessarily limits the size of a view.  I've tried `RelativeLayout`s with no success.  `Flexbox` seems geared toward horizontal spacing.  I've reviewed other questions/answers, such as [Height half fill_parent xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748872/height-half-fill-parent-xml), [Divide screen in two half and place imageview on half-half both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645060/divide-screen-in-two-half-and-place-imageview-on-half-half-both), [2 LinearLayouts, each half the parent size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095173/2-linearlayouts-each-half-the-parent-size), [How to spread the Views in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523415/how-to-spread-the-views-in-android), etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_Main_MyPursuitsOuter_Wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/preD_scenarios_min_height">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_Main_MyPursuitsOuter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder_outer"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    …
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_Main_ScenariosOuter_Wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/preD_scenarios_min_height"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_Main_ScenariosOuter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder_outer"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        …

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using this code I get an output like figure 1.  There is a lot of blank space between the views when View 1 isn't large enough to fill the space, and I'm concerned that if View 2 grows large enough it will cause View 1 to be too small.

Figure 1:
[image: Current output]

If both Views can't fill the entire screen, it should look like Figure 2.

Figure 2:
[image: Both maximized]

If one View needs less than half of the screen, and the other needs more than the remaining space, it should look like Figure 3, with the applicable View taking the remaining space and its ELV scrolling as needed.

Figure 3:
[image: One maximized and other scrolling]

Finally, if both views need more than half of the screen, then it should look like Figure 4, with each View geting half and both ELVs scrolling as needed.

Figure 4:
[image: Both scrolling]

**UPDATE:**
Based upon @Sultan Mahmud recommendation, I developed the following method.  I tried using `ViewTreeObserver` but it ended up invoking multiple resizings since I have two different `View`s being dynamically updated via `AsyncTask`s.  So instead I used `post` on one of my `View`s (likely the one that will take the longest to populate; may need to do a post for both if ).  I call this method from `onResponse` for each of the `AsyncTask`s, from `onResume` (to account for real estate changes from screen rotations), and whenever the user manually adds or deletes an item from one of the `ExpandableListView`s.

New method:

```java
private void measureViews(){
//        final String METHOD = "In measureViews,";
//
//        Log.d(LOG_CLASS, String.format(Locale.US, "%s Started.", METHOD));

        mLL_MyPursuits_Outer_Wrapper.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Get parent LinearLayout dimensions
                parentPadding = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin) * 2.0);
                parentHeight = mLL_Main_Wrapper.getHeight() - (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin) * 2.0);
                parentWidth = mLL_Main_Wrapper.getWidth() - (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin) * 2.0);

                //Get MyPursuits LinearLayout desired height
                mLL_MyPursuits_Outer_Wrapper.measure(
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentHeight, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
                myPursuitsDesiredHeight = mLL_MyPursuits_Outer_Wrapper.getMeasuredHeight();

                //Get PreD_Scenarios LinearLayout desired height
                mLL_Scenarios_Outer_Wrapper.measure(
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parentHeight, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
                scenariosDesiredHeight = mLL_Scenarios_Outer_Wrapper.getMeasuredHeight();

                //Determine if either or both are bigger than half
                boolean isMyPursuitsBiggerThanHalf = (myPursuitsDesiredHeight > (parentHeight / 2));
                boolean isPreD_ScenariosBiggerThanHalf = (scenariosDesiredHeight > (parentHeight / 2));

                //Set LayoutParams
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsMyPursuits;
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsScenarios;
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsZeroWeight = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        0
                );
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsOneWeight = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        0,
                        1
                );

                if ((myPursuitsDesiredHeight + scenariosDesiredHeight) <= parentHeight){
                    paramsMyPursuits = paramsZeroWeight;
                    paramsScenarios = paramsZeroWeight;
                } else if (!isMyPursuitsBiggerThanHalf && isPreD_ScenariosBiggerThanHalf){
                    paramsMyPursuits = paramsZeroWeight;
                    paramsScenarios = paramsOneWeight;
                } else if (isMyPursuitsBiggerThanHalf && !isPreD_ScenariosBiggerThanHalf){
                    paramsMyPursuits = paramsOneWeight;
                    paramsScenarios = paramsZeroWeight;
                } else {
                    paramsMyPursuits = paramsOneWeight;
                    paramsScenarios = paramsOneWeight;
                }
                mLL_MyPursuits_Outer_Wrapper.setLayoutParams(paramsMyPursuits);

                mLL_Scenarios_Outer_Wrapper.setLayoutParams(paramsScenarios);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set layout weight programmatically after taking the decision based on your condition. Like if the first condition match for half screen occupied then divide layout weight on both views.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   0,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    1.0f
);
first_layout.setLayoutParams(param);
second_layout..setLayoutParams(param);
```